# What exactly is the grand mean in ANOVA?

Tags: anova

The grand mean in AVONA, what exactly is it referring to?

Is it the population mean or the mean of the treatment samples?

Answer (score 2):

The grand mean is the arithmetic mean of the group means. It should be clear from the context if the sample version or the population version is meant.

It is *not* necessarily the mean of the pooled values (equality holds e.g. if groups are equally large). But at least it is a weighted average with weights being inversly proportional to the group sizes, so that values in small groups are weighted up.

Answer (score 1):

It's the overall mean of all your sampled units. If you took the mean of your treatment means then that is the grand mean